# how to pagify genre search result on the movie database

Tags: php, web, themoviedb-api

I have a website that I'm building on my localhost using the MVC design pattern. I have button on click that will display all the genres in TheMovieDatabase which I got using the TheMovieDatabaseAPI. On click of a genre I get data for Page 1 with 20 results. But, I couldn't figure out how to request the results for page 2. These requests are made using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are taking about pagination using, I am also assuming you are using mySQL as database, I am not sure which framework you are using,
Here is a function i use, you can build around this

```
 function get_movie($page = 1){
    global $database_connection;
    $start = 0; //Don't modify this
    $limit = 10; //set this to 20 to display 20 movies per page
    $start = ($page - 1)* $limit;

    //get the movie from the table
    $sql = "SELECT genre FROM movie_table LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysqli_query($database_connection, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<div>$row['genre']</div>";
    }

    $movie_rows = mysqli_num_rows (mysqli_query($database_connection ,"SELECT * FROM movie_table"));
    $total = ceil($testimony_rows / $limit);
    if (isset($page)){
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<ul class='pager'>";
        if($page > 1) {
            echo "<a href='?page=".($page - 1)."' style='float: left;' class=' w3-sand w3-btn w3-margin w3-round'>Previous</a>";
        }
        for($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) {
            if($i == $page) { echo "<li class='active current'>".$i."</li>"; }

            else { echo "<li><a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; }
        }
        if($page != $total) {
            echo "<a href='?page=".($page + 1)."' class='w3-btn w3-margin w3-sand w3-round'>Next</a>";
        }
        echo "</ul></div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use limit and offset to get the result for page 2.

Example :- if you are using query builder to get the results

```
$limit = 20;
$offset = 21;
$queryBuilder->select('d')
            ->from(<table name>, 'd')
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->setParameter('limit', $limit)
            ->setParameter('offset', $offset);
```

If you are using raw query :

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 20 OFFSET 21
```

Else you can use paginator too

```
$paginator  = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query);

$totalItems = count($paginator);
$pagesCount = ceil($totalItems / $pageSize);

// now get one page's items:
$paginator
    ->getQuery()
    ->setFirstResult($pageSize * ($currentPage-1)) // set the offset
    ->setMaxResults($pageSize); // set the limit

foreach ($paginator as $pageItem) {
    echo "<li>" . $pageItem->getName() . "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Yes but I was wondering about the URL request needed to send to the API.
This is the API I'm talking about: http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference/genres/genreidmovies/get?console=1

Comment: Which particular API you are calling .